# inlining svg image in a markdown cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

My question is related to the wish of publishing a self contained notebook

I have a Markdown cell in a notebook of mine that references an external image file

```
so far

![](example.svg "Example")

so good
```

Is it possible to inline the file content in the MD cell?

Comment: If cells accepted HTML I could simply copy the file content inside the cell. — `%%html` cell magic is not a plausible solution because I cannot guarantee that the notebook, when distributed, can access the same nbextension that I'd use to hide the embarrassingly long input cell. —
 Other possibilities based on `display()` are however connected to a code cell that exposes either an external reference  or the whole file content... — The hypothesized Markdown solution is appealing to me because the same cell is either unrendered (SVG code visible)  or rendered (ONLY the image is visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to distill some wisdom from the answers and the comments I've received.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323948/2749397) from [Shammel Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3682217/shammel-lee) is the closest to an accettable answer, the *idea* behind that answer is the correct idea, but too many details make me think that I cannot accept it.

1. The recourse to external sites, it's true that I'm going to publish the notebooks but my files and other details of my digital identity are not the business of anyone (as far as possible :), especially when Python standard library is perfectly up to the task.
2. The usually unnecessary step of uuencoding the SVG string.
3. The missing distinction between the header for a not-uuencoded string and the uuencoded one, as noted in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139441/inlining-svg-image-in-a-markdown-cell#comment122909008_44323948) by [Aristide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173003/aristide).

I have written a Python script that copies the quoted SVG content, plus the headers etc, to the clipboard

```
$ python3 svg2clip figure03.svg
```

so that you can paste (Ctrl-V) the required stuff into a markdown cell.

```
from sys import argv
from urllib import parse
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, TimeoutExpired

svg = open(argv[1]).read()
inlined = ('![svg image](data:image/svg+xml,' +
           parse.quote(svg) +
           ')'
           ).encode('utf8')
p = Popen(["xclip", "-selection", "clipboard"],
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
try:
    p.communicate(inlined, timeout=0.020)
except TimeoutExpired:
    pass
```

---

PS1 — if someone knows how to terminate command execution in a simpler way, please comment...
PS2 — the script works on Linux, where `xclip` is usually present or can be easily installed, but afaict similar utilities are available also for different environments, just modify the `Popen` first argument.

Answer (score 23):

This method doesn't require an internet connection…

1. base64-encode the `<svg>` markup (eg. paste svg at [base64encode.org](https://www.base64encode.org/))
2. URL-encode the base64-encoded string (eg. paste base64 string at [urlencoder.org](https://www.urlencoder.org/))
3. Put the resulting string in `![alt text](data:image/svg+xml,<paste_your_svg_string_here> "title")`

The result would be a string similar to the following that can be inserted into a Jupyter Notebook Markdown cell…

`![svg image](data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20100%20100%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2250%22%20cy%3D%2250%22%20r%3D%2240%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A)`

Comment: An acceptable answer, in my opinion, details how do I perform the steps you merely sketched.

Comment: @gboffi please mark as the correct answer if this satisfies your original problem or advise on how to make this answer more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @gboffi You can test by copying the string at the bottom into a Markdown cell.

Comment: Works for me without base64-encoding the `<svg>` markup.

Comment: is there anyway to use a variable for the svg file name?

Comment: This is IMO the best answer :) Thanks @shammel-lee

Comment: The only problem here is that the encoding site is not that intuitive, I used https://www.base64-image.de/ and no explanations were needed

Comment: for base64 encoding, replace `data:image/svg+xml` by `data:image/svg+xml;base64`.

Comment: For anyone else who's looking for a way to do this without recourse to some external website, urllib from Python has a function that will do it for you; see [this blog post](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/).

Comment: `<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20100%20100%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2250%22%20cy%3D%2250%22%20r%3D%2240%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A">` is the HTML representation.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, It is possible to include SVG image in jupyter notebook.

1. **Using markdown syntax**:

`![Alt text](https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/logos/cc.logo.svg)`

2. **Using HTML**:

`<img style="float: right;" src="https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/logos/cc.logo.svg">`

I tried these options on Jupyter Notebook Server version  4.3.1

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is interested, here it is what I've done to share a self contained notebook.

My half-baked solution was to split the Markdown cell and insert a code cell
`display(HTML(open('example.svg').read()))`
replacing the Markdown directive `![](example.svg "Example")`.

Because the file content is stored in an output cell, the saved notebook
can be shared, in a self contained way, using a service like [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org), with all its limitations. If someone chooses to download my notebook they, sort of, downloads also my SVG code, doesn't they?

OTOH, if I share using a service like [Microsoft Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/) (that, at least in the current, Spring 2017, *"Preview"* incarnation allows anyone with a Microsoft account  to interact with my notebook) anyone trying to run that code cell will be hurt  — it is however  possible to implement a cross hosted solution, using the Markdown image directive pointing to a file served through HTTP. But this cross hosting is what I was trying to avoid in the first instance... don't ask me why :-(...